# Android open InputStream from relative uri to ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT?

Tags: android, relative-path, permission-denied, android-contentresolver, storage-access-framework

I'am trying to open multiple files relative to a json configuration file in android 4.4 (api level 19),
I used

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType({mime});
this.startActivityForResult(intent, {code});
```

to let the user find te configuration file, and from there open multiple files that I know the path from the config file.

But i get

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: 
Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadStorageProvider
uri content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/{relative file}
requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

I dont want to use user interfaces to open the other files, so I tried adding the following permissions without getting any results

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS "/>
```

I would rather have the files separated and not in a blob or a zip file

Comment: have you put the runtime permission for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and MANAGE_DOCUMENTS?

Comment: I just tried that, I can get READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, but not MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, and still get Permission denial.
im using minSdkVersion 19, so tried with ActivityCompat.requestPermissions

Comment: "I'am trying to open multiple files" -- your code is not really related to opening files. If you need to limit the user to files on the filesystem that your app has the ability to access directly, use [a file chooser library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35?sort=created), not a system `Intent` like `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` only gives you access to exactly the file (or files, if you use [`EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE)) that the user selects.

You can use [ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE) to allow the user to select a folder - you'll then get access to all files in that folder (and their subfolders).

Comment: ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE was added in API level 21, Forgot to specify, but I'm using minSdkVersion 19, so I cant use that, I think I'll just use zip files :'(

Comment: Correct, there's no equivalent pre-API 21.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to let the user choose multiple files from a file chooser, you can do the following:

*It's part of my app, you can adjust it for your needs. This works starting from API 18*

```
private void openFileChooser() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    i.setType("*/*");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE_DOC_ALL_FILES);
}
```

Then here is how you get the selected Uris:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_DOC_ALL_FILES && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        if (data == null || (data.getData() == null && data.getClipData() == null)) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.invalid_source, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }


        //get result after user action (selecting files) and transform it into array of Uris
        Uri[] uriPaths;
        if (data.getData() != null) { // only one uri was selected by user
            uriPaths = new Uri[1];
            uriPaths[0] = data.getData();
        } else if (data.getClipData() != null) {
            int selectedCount = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
            uriPaths = new Uri[selectedCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < selectedCount; i++) {
                uriPaths[i] = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
            }
        } 
}
```