# Can't set image URI because Permission Denial: opening provider

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Good afternon,
I crate an app with Room database to save items (name, desc, price, image). I have 3 activities. The 1st activity for create, the 2nd MainActivity with RecyclerView and the last activity (ChangeActivity) open when I click on item in MainActivity. When I create an item I pick image and save uri in database. I want to set image in ImageView in ChangeActivity but get
`Unable to start activity ComponentInfo {hop.test.aah/hop.test.aah.ChangeActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{7a3e034 25078:hop.test.aah/u0a95} (pid=25078, uid=10095) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs`.
I tried some solutions what I found but nothing help or maybe I wrong and it is why I ask some help.

ChangeActivity:

In manifest I only add READ_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION and WRITE_EXTERNAL PERMISSION.
This is how I pick image:

UPD 2:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
val resolver = applicationContext.contentResolver
        val flags: Int = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or
                Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
         resolver.takePersistableUriPermission(image!!, flags)
and fun to get
@Throws(IOException::class)
    fun getBitmapFromUri(uri: Uri): Bitmap {
        val parcelFileDescriptor: ParcelFileDescriptor? =
            contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r")
        val fileDescriptor: FileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor!!.fileDescriptor
        val image: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor)
        parcelFileDescriptor.close()
        return image
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android open InputStream from relative uri to ACTION\_OPEN\_DOCUMENT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53246026/android-open-inputstream-from-relative-uri-to-action-open-document)

Comment: You do not need any permission.

Comment: If you store the uri and use it later it is not valid anymore if you used ACTION_GET_CONTENT.

Comment: @AgentP it is not my solution because I want to set image already in activity. I tried use this solution with intent but didn't work.

Comment: @blackapps I save uri of picked image in DB and try to set image uri for imageView from DB. What do you recommend to use? I tried to use ACTION_PICK but gallery didn't open and app just crashed without error in log

Comment: Use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT and take persistable uri permission in onActivityResult before you store the uri.

Comment: @blackapps I create resolver and fun to getBitmap but can't understand how to use it.

Comment: `resolver.takePersistableUriPermission(image...` ? What is `image`?

Comment: Call getBitmapFromUri() in onActivityResult() to see if it works correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216887/discussion-between-savera-sleemy-and-blackapps).

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        intent.type = "image/jpeg"
        startActivityForResult(
            Intent.createChooser(
                intent,
                getString(R.string.chooser_title)
            ), RC_GALLERY)

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == RC_GALLERY) {
                imgUri = data?.data

                val contentResolver = applicationContext.contentResolver
                val takeFlags: Int = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or
                        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION

                imgUri?.let { contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(it, takeFlags) }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Switch to `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`.

Step #2: In `onActivityResult()`, when you get the `Uri`, [call `takePersistableUriPermission()` on a `ContentResolver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver?hl=en#takePersistableUriPermission(android.net.Uri,%20int))

Then, and only then, will you be able to save the `Uri` in a database and use it to access content in the future.

With your current approach, the `Uri` works for the activity that receives the `onActivityResult()` call, but it will not work for future processes.

Comment: Can you explain more popular how to use it? Check please updated question.

Comment: @saverasleemy: Call `getContentResolver()` on your `Activity` to get a `ContentResolver`. You can see the use of `takePersistableUriPermission()` in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#persist-permissions).

Comment: I saved it in DB but setImageURI didn't work. I don't understood something really

Comment: I did resolver, take uri, create fun getBitmapFromUri() and in activity where user choose picture from gallery in imageView it shows by `imageView.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromUri(image))`. "image" is Uri what I get in `val image = data?.data` but in other activity when I try `imageFromDatabase.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromUri(uri))` "uri" is `item.image` from database or `intent.getStringExtra()` I tried all. And it still doesn't work. Help one more time please. And now i get "No content provider: android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver@65f567b" error

Comment: @saverasleemy: It looks like you turned the wrong thing into a string. You called `toString()` on a `ContentResolver`.

Comment: I didn't call `toString()`. If you about `getStringExtra()` it was only try fix my app, something like last breath. So, I still didn't find some mistakes and issues. Can you send you project just for check 2 files-activities? If you have a time.